# Transforming SQL to HQL

Tags: sql, hql

my table is the following:

```
Id   Timestamp            name_id     testobject_id 
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  1
3  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  1
1  | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 1        |  1
4  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  2
5  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  2
```

I want the last record of each group (name_id). But i only want the results where testobject_id = 1

This SQL works just fine:

```
SELECT *
    FROM checkresult
    WHERE test_object_id = 4
    AND timestamp IN (
        SELECT MAX(timestamp)
        FROM checkresult
        WHERE test_object_id = 4    
        GROUP BY name_id
    );
```

My HQL does not work.

```
FROM checkresult as cr 
 WHERE cr.testobject = :testobject 
  AND cr.timestamp IN ( 
   MAX(cr.timestamp) 
    FROM checkresult as result WHERE result.testobject = :testobject 
     GROUP BY result.checkName)
```

I am thankful for every help.

Desired Output:

```
Id   Timestamp            name_id     testobject_id 
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  1
3  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  1
```

Comment: Why did you remove the second `select` keyword? And what does "does not work" mean? You get an error? No results? Wrong results? System crash?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought, that i don't need the second select, cause i don't need the first in hql. With the second select it runs just fine :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `MAX(cr.timestamp)` in your second SQL statement.
But it should be

```
MAX(result.timestamp) 
FROM checkresult as result WHERE result.testobject = :testobject 
GROUP BY result.checkName
```

Also what is your error message?